# Can anyone explain in layman terms that while opening my websites using domain name its shows https but using static IP it shows http. why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-lightsail, static-ip-address

Can anyone explain in layman terms that while opening my websites using domain name its shows https but using static IP it shows http. why???
I am using this article to change http to https :
Enabling HTTPS on your WordPress instance in Amazon Lightsail
https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-enabling-https-on-wordpress

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your link does not work. Also you can't have valid public non-self signed SSL certificate for IP address, thus https does not work with IPs.

Comment: You have Let's encrypt SSL certificate issued for `www.gorakhpurgraphs.com` not for the IP address `3.7.246.192`. That's why.

Comment: Thank you @YuriGinsburg  How can i encrypt it for IP address ? When I am searching on google of my website it shows both  domain associated address website(with https) and ip address website (with http), Is it security risk that my ip address is shown ? Is i have to add cloudfare ? please help me.

Comment: @Ankitgupta You can use the `rewrite` directive in web server settings to redirect IP address to the domain name.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg 
I do what you say but still problem is not solved and If  web server is set up incorrectly, it may server website for both  web server's IP address and your domain name. The strange user experience aside, having  website accessible to search engines through both  IP address.

Comment: @Yuri Ginsburg can you remove the ip address from your comment please type xxx..xxx on that place.

Answer (score 0):

Because Let's Encrypt does issue certificates for only domain names, not for IP addresses.

Comment: How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

uSo,now you know that certficate is issued the domain, not IP address.
To redirescr request that starts with IP address you can use something like nelow  in the `.htаccеss`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^3\.nnn\.nnn\.nnn$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gorakhpurgraphs.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```